# How to model React Modal Workflow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, react-redux, modal-dialog

I have an web application in React which have multiple react components used to render different views. For the particular use-case, the back-end vends out an action to UI layer, and for this particular action, the view has to be shown on modal.

The modal has multiple buttons in it on click of which, we have to map to existing react component inside this modal only.

So basically, until unless someone closes the modal, all the further screens on the click on buttons in this should be shown inside the modal.

Application uses React, Redux and Epics. Different URLs are not enabled for the component. I'm relatively new to the react, so don't completely understand the routing concepts.

Question:
How can I model this in a way which provides best user experience, is maintainable and allows me to re-use the existing components.

**Approaches I have thought:**

1. Create separate components for each existing one, which wraps the existing component around Modal. For e.g. I have component A, so I create another component AModal, which internally refers to A inside  tags.
   On each click of button inside original modal, I'll close this background modal and open the corresponding modal component, in the example above AModal.

Concerns: This will lead to hazy experience, as closing and opening of modals will be visible. Also depending upon the modal sizes for each individual components, experience might be even more degraded.

2. Create WflowContainerComponent which uses all of the original components inside it. So the modal and height/width is defined by the outer component and the view inside it changes as per the requirement and react/redux states.

Concerns: With every added functionality (i.e. button click on original WflowContainerComponent) have to include each individual component in it. And if each of the individual component requires certain inputs from the state, then the props list of WflowContainerComponent will keep on extending beyond control.

Is there a better way wherein, I can just let react know that render each of the next component on the modal only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this might be helpful or not. But what you can do, If all the existing components are connected to redux, Then you can create a Modal Container and pass the other components as children **(with props)** and remove the animation CSS Just for this component only, So it does not show like glitching.